# Android Studio freezes on indexing

Tags: android, indexing, virtualbox, genymotion, freeze

my project was working well but suddenly when I ran it on my phone, Android Studio freezes and I should stop it from task manager. 
before this happens I installed "Geny motion" & "Virtual Box", but when the error occurred I uninstalled them. but the problem insisted.

[image: android studio freezes on indexing]

**Solutions I've tried**

1. I uninstalled it and installed it again
2. I unplugged and plugged in my device
3. I disabled android indexing from setting

None of the above solutions worked.

Comment: Did you try using the built-in emulator rather than your device?

Comment: Since the build process on an external device may tend to cause these problems at times

Comment: There may be other areas to be looked into, like any infinite loops running inside your code. Another thing is try connecting other devices rather than the same device.

Comment: @TaraWilfred  - I just tried it and it freezes still.

Comment: Are there any errors being output as it freezes? If so could you provide those in the question as well?

Comment: Happens like this to me then  I run project then its already building or something like this. This is probably minor bug off Android Studio. Nothing you should worry about.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I had today this exact problem. None of the above helped me until I found  simple solution [here](https://teamtreehouse.com/community/android-studio-is-stuck-on-the-gradle-build-screenkeeps-saying-scanning-files-to-index) 
Just run File -> Invalidate Cache and Restart
That simple and it works!!!

Comment: Your are Killing it ! Simple and smart. Thx

Answer (score 5):

Delete all Android Studio data - .gradle .android .androidstudio folders from your home folder. And all project build folders gradle and iml files.

Comment: For me this problem occurs when I am running test with coverage. But when gradle built is over and indexing starts (before actual running test starts) AS freezes to the hell :( Other options like `invalidate and restart` isn't working. I was really hoping this would help but didnt. Even in sample project if I am making test case of single add function it is freezing.

Comment: Removing `~/.android` would delete at least one emulator in my installation.

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me.

```
1.Close the project
2.Remove the project
3.Close Android Studio
4.Open it again
5.Open the project
```

Enjoy Coding!

Answer (score 1):

I checked my java file and I saw somehow all the code in one of my java files was replaced with "NULL NULL NULL NULL....."
I deleted the file and the application runs without a problem.

Comment: Unbelievable. I had same cause and solution. My android studio froze when I was editing a kotlin file, I tried several times to write the same content, every time same crash. then I did "save all" after each paste, eventually it froze again at the exact same click where before and after that when I restarted (again) it got stuck on reindexing. I found this answer and it gave me the idea to delete the file and after that indexing got unstuck. NB! the answer I am commenting on, is from 2016, it is now 2023!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Android Studio (3.1.3) froze on me while editing a source file.  I waited and finally killed the process in Task Manager (Windows).  Twice I tried to start up again and both times it got stuck with the "indexing..." message in the lower right.  Both times I ended the process in Task Manager.

I looked in the source folder of the project I was working on. The source file I had been editing when it froze was "Receipt.java".  There was another file in the src folder "Receipt.java__jb_tmp__".  I deleted that file and Android Studio started up fine.  It looks like I lost some edits, though.

When I did start up, it detected there had been some error and offered to submit a report.

Answer (score 1):

If the project is large & has a lot of modules, you might need to increase the  Allocated Heap Size for Android Studio.

Go to `Edit Custom VM Options` from Help menu and increase the value for `-Xms` and `-Xmx`

This is what I'm using

```
-Xms2048m
-Xmx8192m
-XX:MaxPermSize=2048m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=1024m
-XX:+UseCompressedOops
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case color was declared as invalid, Android Studio ignored that and during building it froze. I had to remove the file, let it index, paste it back and fix the color string (it gave me error when I entered the pasted file)

Answer (score 0):

just rename project folder then open IDE, it will show

[image]

now rename back to origin folder name, click open project

it work on my case

Answer (score 0):

I have older project with sdk version 22, when I open it in android studio 3.1.2 on macOS. It keep indexing forever, everything was installed and configured properly but indexing loop never stopped.

Following worked for me

> File > Invalidate caches/restart… > Invalidate caches/restart

Answer (score 0):

Go to the File menu and click the option Invalidate Caches / Restart This will solve the problem ! Enjoy ;)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, Android studio was stuck longer at indexing at specific folder
D:\Java\andsdk\sources\android-33
I deleted that folder (android-33) and restarted Android studio
This trick worked for me and Android studio started working correctly